# Table reload without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my page , I have a table in which the data is iterated from a list. And I have a search button that gets a key and returns a the list with new data using Ajax/jQuery. Now Can I refresh the table with new data with out refreshing my whole page..?

Comment: What you can do is returning a new table (html) within your new data from your ajax call. And then replace it with your existing table.

Comment: Is it possible at any cost to just refresh the table or div that covers the table with new data..? @NiZa

Comment: Yes, the only danger is that your jQuery (if there is) isn't working anymore for that specific of new html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in your php file, or which file it may be, a table with the same html structure as your current one, but than with new data that you have received by doing the ajax call.

```
$.post( "newTable.php", function( data ) {
     $( ".currentTable" ).html( data );
});
```